# TikZ not working with ConTeXt on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: tikz-pgf, context, ubuntu

I recently switched distributions to Ubuntu 17.10. My ConTeXt code that recently worked fine on NixOS now do not seem to find TikZ anymore:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary[positioning,fit,calc]
```

This results in the following error:

```
tex error       > tex error on line 5 in file header.tex: ! Undefined control sequence

<recently read> \usetikzlibrary
```

I installed the packages `context` and `texlive-pictures`. When I got the error, for good measure, I also installed `texlive-full`, but the error did not go away. How can I fix it?

Comment: Apparently their package is broken.  You should report it on their bugtracker: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bugs

Comment: [Done](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/1734097). In the meantime, is there a workaround?

Comment: As a workaround try standalone context: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Ubuntu#With_ConTeXt_Standalone_.E2.80.93_should_work_with_all_Ubuntu_versions

Comment: Standalone does not seem to work with simplefonts. `lua error       > lua error on line 144 in file /usr/local/context/tex/texmf-modules/tex/context/third/simplefonts/t-simplefonts.mkiv:

...ext/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/luat-cod.lua:50: bad argument #1 to 'gmatch' (string expected, got nil)`

Comment: @flyx: Can you please post a MWE. If tikz module is working correctly with context standalone, then you may want to close this question and open another one showing the error with simplefonts.

Comment: @Aditya Right, will do as separate question. I will leave this question open until the Ubuntu bug is fixed as reference to others.

Comment: @Aditya Fixed it myself by using `\definefontfamily` and `\setupbodyfont` instead of the older `\setmainfont`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems that this problem is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>[Too long for a comment]</sub>

---

There is something else wrong with your TeXlive installation.  Using the Ubuntu 17.10 (Artful) Docker image and installing `context` and `texlive-pictures` the MWE you posted with the bug performs just fine.

Command to reproduce:

```bash
sudo docker run --rm -v `pwd`/test.tex:/test.tex -it ubuntu:artful /bin/bash -c "apt-get update; apt-get install -y context texlive-pictures; context test.tex"
```

where `test.tex` is of course located in the working directory and has the content:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary[positioning,fit,calc]

\starttext
  Lorem Ipsum
\stoptext
```